# Can a bulged capacitor prevent a CPU from booting?

Tags: capacitor, cpu, component-failure

I am trying to revive my old CPU. But it won't turn on. The fans don't turn ON, but they are working. PSU is also working. I have changed my CMOS battery.

I found that one of the capacitors has bulged slightly. I want to know if this bulged capacitor is causing my CPU to not boot?
[image: image1]

[image: image2]

The capacitor between DIMM2 and IDE2 has bulged.

Comment: It's possible but almost impossible to tell without a schematic.

Comment: Let's try other things before assuming the CPU is the issue. When you try to turn on your PC, do you hear any clicking? This might indicate a power supply failure. Do you case fans move a little bit when hit the power button? We need a little more information on what you observe when you try to turn on the power. It could very well be that capacitor that's causing issues but let's think of other possibilities.

Comment: @RonBeyer I highly doubt the OP will be able to have access to a schematic.

Comment: @KingDuken No nothing happens. Actually I tested for the SMPS by connecting the green wire and the ground of 20/24 pin cable. The SMPS fan turned ON, so I think there's no problem there.

Comment: If it's not a power supply failure, you should still be able to see the fans (both CPU fan and case fans) slightly budge when you hit the power.

Comment: @RonBeyer It is an old model. I think I bought it in 2004 or 2005. I will attach it if I find anything

Comment: @KingDuken I know they work because I used a 10 V battery to test them.

Comment: @VishalDalwadi I'm not asking if the fans work or not. I'm just asking if you simply hit the power button with the power supply plugged in, do you see any movement from your fans? I'm not suggesting that your fans aren't working. Your power supply should still cause the fans to move a little bit (or twitch a little) before the motherboard finds out the something's wrong with the CPU.

Comment: @KingDuken No there is no movement.

Comment: I saw your edit. So the capacitor is between the DIMM slot and the IDE hard drive connector. Your CPU should still be able to boot the computer but it could give you some type of NMI exception saying that there's some physical damage to the motherboard. Back to what I was saying. If there is no fan movement then it's not impossible to eliminate the possibility of a PSU malfunction. I'd measure the voltage of each pin, particularly the one that goes directly into the motherboard (the longer one).

Comment: @KingDuken Okay I will try that and edit the question with the result. Thanks.

Comment: Caps don't have to be bulging to stop electronic equipment working, I recently revived a TFT monitor by changing out all the electrolytics in the PSU, none were bulged! If one's bulged, change them all, at least around the PSU for the CPU.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I found that one of the capacitors has bulged slightly. I want to know
>   if this bulged capacitor is causing my CPU to not boot?

It sure can, even if the cap still retains its capacitance, the ESR is most likely too high. This will cause more ripple than normal and could interfere with digital signaling (the power supply needs to be clean). Pull the cap off the board. Check the cap with an ESR meter (should be under 1Ω or even lower) and replace. I would replace if it was bulging, make sure it has a higher voltage level than listed on the cap, and the same or more capacitance. This may or may not fix the problem.

Check the power with a Digital Multi Meter and check the AC ripple in mV it should be lower than 25mV and hopefully in the 10-5mV range.

Comment: I don't have an ESR meter. But I don't mind spending on having the capacitor replaced. But is there any other way to know the ESR value.

Comment: @voltagespike Wouldn't the CPU still be able to power up the motherboard and at least give an NMI exception? OP edited their question and mentioned that the capacitor was between the DIMM and IDE slot.

Comment: No way to tell without seeing where the actual line goes. If the voltage ripple was too high it could cause many problems.

Comment: I thought it could be a PSU issue since the OP mentioned that none of the fans budge (or at least twitch a little) when he turns on the power to the board. They did mention that the LED on the PSU was working. It could be an eFuse problem. Voltage ripples in the eFuse can cause some crazy issues.

Comment: You didn't say what motherboard you have, but Dell used a large batch of bad caps about 15 years ago, other vendors may have used them also. We had 3 PCs at my workplace with many bulging caps and I have one at home. Same issue as you have, won't turn on. Two at my workplace have been fixed. I have purchased caps to fix mine, but haven't got around to it yet.

Comment: @Mattman944 The problem was industry wide, someone stole an electrolyte formula but didn't steal the whole thing, they sold it to another company and many manufacturers had cap problems

Comment: @Mattman944 It was Compaq. I think it is now HP.